# How to describe players that are consistently playing in a team?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

I am writing a description about player's performance and their participation in matches, but I am stuck in trying to find the right word for describing a player who has been participating in nearly every match for his team.

Comment: I would use "regular" to describe a player who has been participating in nearly every match for his team. As for the second part of your question, have you tried Thesaurus?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @Arun You must post that as an "answer," along with why you think it's a suitable answer. Better include reference to a dictionary for meaning and usage.

Comment: @Kris Thank you for the suggestion, I will edit the question right away.

Comment: You mean the player is playing consistently? As in playing well? Because one can play badly and also be consistent.

Answer (score 26):

A very good option would be:
**[regular](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/regular_2)** (Oxford Learner's Dictionary)

> a person who often plays in a particular team, takes part in a particular television show, etc.
>
> - *We are missing six first-team regulars because of injury.*

Answer (score 11):

Some options would be

**Starter**

which technically means that they play at the beginning of a game, but if you called someone a "starter" most people (in AmE, at least) would assume you meant they played a large portion of the time in most of their team's games.

Ex: Who's playing QB for the Patriots this year? Tom Brady will be the starter, but Malcolm Mitchell might get some playing time at the end of some games to get him some experience.

**Everyday Player**
a player who plays in all, or nearly all, of a team's games.

Ex: Since the Cubs infield is already full of great players, David Bote only gets occasionally playing time, but he could be an everyday player on many other teams.

Answer (score 9):

Try **first-string**

[Mirriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/first-string):

> 1 : being a regular as distinguished from a substitute (as on a team)

Anecdotally, I've only heard this term used in reference to American football, but the definition from Mirriam-Webster seems to fit your need perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Try **stalwart**

> A loyal, reliable, and hard-working supporter of or participant in an organization or team.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stalwart

Comment: Please don't just nominate words and then link to copied text. You still have to write your own answer, in your own words, with an explanation of why you think this is a suitable answer to the request. We're trying to build up a library of expert answers for future visitors, and that requires original content not just dictionary quotes. Otherwise we're just somebody else’s thesaurus with voting added.

Comment: Please don't just spam replies criticizing other peoples posts. I get that it's part of your power trip, but I was just trying to help. I can rehash an actual definition of a word, but seems unnecessary.

Comment: Dictionary spam does not enhance the quality of our library of answers. We need something original to do that. Otherwise we're just a thesaurus with voting, which is ***NOT*** with the charter of the English Language & Users site in specific nor of Stack Exchange in general. I can write custom messages each time, but the point remains the same: without original content, this is not an answer in your own words.

Comment: @moote Please join our discussion on this topic over in meta.  I think you would have a valuable perspective as a newcomer to our site.  https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11636/on-answering-word-requests

Answer (score 1):

In British English, you might want to consider "**[Mainstay](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mainstay)**", the principle being that this player or players would be the foundation on which the team (comprising lesser or transient players) is built. The implication is *solidity and longevity*.

> *Celtic central defender **Jack Hendry can become a mainstay for Scotland
> for the next decade,** according to his club manager Brendan Rodgers.*
>
> *The 22-year-old made his international debut in Tuesday's friendly
> victory over Hungary in Budapest.*
>
> *"He has the quality to play for Celtic and the international team for
> the next 10 years," said Rodgers.*
>
> <sub><sup>[BBC News: Celtic: Brendan Rodgers tips Jack Hendry to become Scotland mainstay](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/43585407)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try **team player**

> someone who cares more about helping a group or team to succeed than about his or her individual success

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/team%20player